# Using Privacy Parameters Uploading Photos With Facebook API

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

When uploading `images` to my `app` I am trying to allow the user to pick their `privacy settings.`

I specify my privacy `permissions parameters` to

```
    $privacy = array(
    'value' => 'CUSTOM',
    'allow' => 'ID1, ID2, ID3'
    );
```

The photo uploads to the auto generated album the api created but the privacy settings on the photo are completely ignored and set to `Only Me`

If I change custom to Anything else it works and the privacy will be open to `FRIENDS FRIENDS_OF_FRIENDS` etc. But for what ever reason the `allow object` is completely ignored.

Once I declare `$privacy` I put it all together like this,

```
$photo = (new FacebookRequest(
$session,
'PHOTO',
'/me/photos',
array (
    'source' => new CURLFile ($location.$name),
    'message' => ($caption),
    'privacy' => json_encode ($privacy)

 )

))->execute()->getGraphObject()->asArray();
```

Comment: Your first problem that you should fix is that the class mentioned in the error message can not be found. I’d recommend using the autoload script that comes with the SDK.